# How to express the idiomatic “It took some getting used to, but ...”?

Tags: выражения

In English, you say:

> It took some (serious) getting used to, but ...

... with the word "some" acting like an intensifier. This colloquial structure essentially takes the form of "It took some + gerund, but ...".

What is a commonly used phrasing in Russian to express this idea? Does the following sound idiomatic enough?

> Привыкнуть к этому мне удалось уж точно не сразу, но ...

Comment: It might make sense not to think about the word 'some' when expressing it in Russian. Cf. Can I have some coffee? - Можно мне кофе (some doesn't really need to be translated). IMO you translation is good.

Answer (score 5):

You may use the remarkable adverb **[с непривычки](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/240080/%D0%A1)**, 'due to lack of habit':

- С непривычки было сложно (даже очень!), но ... теперь даже нравится (*например*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is but it's not an accurate equivalent of the English phrase, there seems to be no set expression in Russian.
Based on the English expression i myself would go with

> Мне пришлось/надо было (постараться) к этому привыкнуть || ... пришлось/надо было к этому привыкать
>
> Мне пришлось (постараться) приучить себя к этому || ... пришлось
> приучать себя к этому
>
> Мне пришлось/надо было приложить усилия, чтобы к этому привыкнуть
>
> Привыкание к этому мне далось непросто/нелегко *(a little less colloquial)*

Imperfective aspect conveys a sense of greater effort. There's also a verb **попривыкнуть** which could better convey the connotation of the English **some**, but its imperfective form is unusable in this context

Comment: What if turn the phrase inside out: "Поначалу было (очень) непривычно, но ..."